# How to install PIP for Python version 3.7.2?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install PIP for python but can't seem to understand how.  I know I will probably be slated for not understanding, but I'm completely lost!
If I follow the address given by python, get-pip.py - I get sent to a random page with lots of binary data, if i type that code into cmd I'm told that get is not defined or it is not an internal or external command that is recognised.
I'm really stuck, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you download `get-pip.py` and ran `python get-pip.py`, correct?

Comment: How do i download get-pip.py?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install pip again using following steps:

- Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to a folder on your computer
- Then run `python get-pip.py`
- Verify a successful installation by opening a command prompt window and navigating to your Python installation's script directory (default is C:\Python27\Scripts). Type pip freeze from this location to launch the Python interpreter.
- On the `System Properties / Advanced tab`, click `Environment Variables` to open `User Variables` and `System Variables`
- Then add the Python installation path to Windows' `PATH ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE`

Comment: copy all python code written in "get-pip.py" and past it in new python file with same name, and put that file in `C:\Python27\Scripts`(default) or where you had installed python.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to provide the path correctly. Open cmd and then set the path for your python installed location

EX:-

```
cd C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
```

2. Then download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and copy to the python installed location(Above location)
3. Run the following command in your cmd

   `python get-pip.py`
4. Check Pip installed. using

   `python -m pip -V`

Comment: I typed that in but got the error code:   File "<stdin>", line 1
    cd C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  (I did put in the correct thing for user btw)

Comment: is your account name user?

Comment: oh i get it you run this code in python interpreter. Just open another cmd

Comment: cd C:\Users\dgosl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 - this is what I put into CMD and it said there was a Syntax error on the C

Comment: Go to your python installed location(folder) then press Alt+D, type cmd and press Enter